# Does sagemaker inference recommendation job support multi model endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to perform load test on sagemaker multimodel endpoint.I found out that we can't run an instance recommendation job for an existing endpoint from this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-recommender-existing-endpoint.html but in the inference recommendation job for without endpoint documentation this is not mentioned.So I just wanted to know how can we run inference recommendation job for multi model endpoint.And since the inference recommendation job will create and invoke endpoint on its side where can i provide extra parameters required for multi model endpoint

I checked this links

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-recommender-existing-endpoint.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-recommender-instance-recommendation.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not at the moment. Inference Recommender only works with RealTime Single Model Endpoints.